# Can't send multiple packets TCP (Multithreaded Server, TcpListener)

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, xna

I've recently tried to add multiplayer support for my XNA game, so I made a Console app Server. It's multithreaded and can handle a No. of clients at the same time. I'm using TcpListener. The problem is that I can only send one packet from the Client to the Server. I mean I can have only one

```cs
//OnConnect Information about client
SendPackage(client.name, client, (int)PackId.Connect);
```

And when I try to add it somewhere else, for example a `ChatHandle()` method where I send `Console.ReadLine()` input, it doesn't work, and the server doesn't reply.

Here's the Client-Side code:

```cs
public static void SendPackage(string data, Client client, int type)
{
    string answer = client.getPayLoadAnswer(data, (short)type);
    Console.WriteLine("sent: {0}", data);
    Console.WriteLine("recieved: {0}", answer);
}
```

And the getPayloadAnswer() method:

```cs
public string getPayLoadAnswer(string payLoad, short id)
{
    List<byte> payloadData = new List<byte>();

    payloadData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(id));
    payloadData.AddRange(MakeString(payLoad));

    client.GetStream().Write(payloadData.ToArray(), 0, payloadData.Count);
    client.GetStream().Read(new byte[2], 0, 2);

    string answer = ReadString(client);

    payloadData.Clear();

    return answer;
}

private byte[] MakeInt(int i)
{
    return BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
}

private byte[] MakeString(string input)
{
    List<byte> data = new List<byte>();

    data.AddRange(MakeInt(Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(input)));
    data.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input));
    return data.ToArray();
}

private int ReadInt(TcpClient client)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[4];
    client.GetStream().Read(data, 0, 4);
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
}

private string ReadString(TcpClient client)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[ReadInt(client)];
    client.GetStream().Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
}
```

Server-Side code:

```cs
private void HandleClient(TcpClient client)
{
    byte[] packetIDData = new byte[2];
    client.GetStream().Read(packetIDData, 0, 2);
    ushort packetID = BitConverter.ToUInt16(packetIDData, 0);
    //Console.WriteLine("packet id: {0}", packetID);
    switch (packetID)
    {
        case 0:
            {                   
                Console.WriteLine("Player {0} connected", ReadData(client));

                RespondToClient(client, "Successfuly connected to server!");

                Players.Add(client, ReadData(client));
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} said: {1}", GetUsername(Players, client), ReadData(client));

                RespondToClient(client, "Sent message successfuly!");
            }
            break;
        default:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknow packet info");
                RespondToClient(client, "Unknow packet info");
            }
            break;
    }
    client.Close();
}

private void RespondToClient(TcpClient client, string response)
{
    List<byte> backData = new List<byte>();
    backData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)0));
       backData.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(response)));
    backData.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response));
    client.GetStream().Write(backData.ToArray(), 0, backData.ToArray().Length);
}

private string ReadData(TcpClient client)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[4];
    client.GetStream().Read(data, 0, 4);

    int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
    data = new byte[length];
    client.GetStream().Read(data, 0, length);

    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: _"it doesn't work, and the server doesn't reply"_ - please investigate further. You're showing a bit too much code, most of which probably is irrelevant. Set breakpoints, walk through the code and point out any _specific_ issues you're having with the code.

Comment: It throws a "Connection was forcibly closed" on the client side app.

Edit: I removed client.Close(), but it still doesn't receive data the second time I call the method.